# error build Pipeline DOESn't contain definition

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, package, augmented-reality, build-pipeline

i'm using unity 2019.4.3
and when I try to build the app for android it gives me this two errors:

1st error:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.management@4.0.1\Editor\XRGeneralBuildProcessor.cs(83,52): error CS0117: 'BuildPipeline' does not contain a definition for 'GetBuildTargetName'
```

2nd error:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.management@4.0.1\Editor\XRGeneralBuildProcessor.cs(36,52): error CS0117: 'BuildPipeline' does not contain a definition for 'GetBuildTargetName'
```

It showed up to me after I installed the `ARCore XR Plugin` package , and I try to downgrade the version of the package.

Comment: i had the same problem and tried the downgrade of the version in the packages with the same results.
i upgrade the unity to 2020.1.17f1 from 2020.1.1f1 and that solved the problem.

Comment: i'll try thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably invisibly updated XR Plugin Management. Try to downgrade AR Core XR Plugin to latest version that does not require XR Management Toolkit upgrade or as suggested update Unity version.

Answer (score 0):

I found this
[link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1795233/unity-hdrp-giving-error.html?_ga=2.55872235.1502989677.1615145912-473643242.1615145912) which helped me resolve the errors.

Specifically, this solution:

I've just encountered this. I had AR Foundation 4.1.3 and ARKit XR Plugin 4.1.3 imported and with them it wouldn't let me downgrade XR Plugin $$anonymous$$anagement to 3.2.16. I've just downgraded both AR Foundation and ARKit to 4.1.1 and now I can downgrade to XR Plugin $$anonymous$$anagement to 3.2.16 and it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Unity version to `2020.3` Worked for me.